# Visualforce Email Template PDF Attachment - Hide Table base on query result

Tags: visualforce, email, attachment, template

I have a PDF attachment created via visualforce email template.  I have a controller grabbing all quote line items, but would like to section off the line items based on a field (which I was able to do).

Now, if there are no line items that fall under the second table's criteria, I don't want to show the table's headers.

If the number of rows with

`QLI.Trade_In_Discount_Grouping__c == 'Additional Discounts'`

is equal to  zero, then don't show the below table at all (so the headers are not just visible).

```
<div id="contentToToggle">    
  <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" 
         style="border-collapse:collapse;border-color:black;font-family:Helvetica;">
  <tr>
    <th width="6%" style="font-size:9pt;"><b>PART #</b></th> 
    <th width="20%" style="font-size:9pt;"><b>DESCRIPTION</b></th>
    <th width="10%" style="text-align:right;font-size:9pt;"><b>DISCOUNT AMOUNT</b></th>
  </tr>   
  <apex:repeat value="{!QuoteLines}" var="QLI"> 
    <apex:variable id="tritemlines" value="" var="tritemlines" rendered="{!QLI.Trade_In_Discount_Grouping__c == 'Additional Discounts'}">  
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size:9pt;">{!QLI.SBQQ__ProductCode__c}</td> 
        <td style="font-size:9pt;">{!QLI.SBQQ__Quantity__c}</td> 
        <td >{!QLI.SBQQ__NetTotal__c}" </td> 
      </tr>    
    </apex:variable>
  </apex:repeat>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea to adjust your template sections is to use standard Visualforce tags with property **rendered**.

Result of that property evaluation will define if component is shown at all.
In this case, it is possible to wrap entire section that needs to be hidden, into `<apex:outputPanel>`, and set property **rendered** based on condition.

In most situations, logic about what should be rendered, is calculated in controller side (in apex)
In this case, example can be next:

**Controller (or extension):**

```
class NiceApexController {
  public Boolean showSection {
    get {
      List<QLI__c> all_qli = getQuoteLines();
      Boolean result = false;
      for (QLI__C qli : all_qli) {
        if (qli.Trade_In_Discount_Grouping__c == 'Additional Discounts') {
          result = true;
          break
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
    private set;
  }
  public List<QLI__c> getQuoteLines() {
    List<QLI__c> result;
    // fill result;
    return result;
  }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered = "{!showSection}" >
  <div id="contentToToggle">    
    <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" 
           style="border-collapse:collapse;border-color:black;font-family:Helvetica;">
    <tr>
      <th width="6%" style="font-size:9pt;"><b>PART #</b></th> 
      <th width="20%" style="font-size:9pt;"><b>DESCRIPTION</b></th>
      <th width="10%" style="text-align:right;font-size:9pt;"><b>DISCOUNT AMOUNT</b></th>
    </tr>   
    <apex:repeat value="{!QuoteLines}" var="QLI"> 
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size:9pt;">{!QLI.SBQQ__ProductCode__c}</td> 
        <td style="font-size:9pt;">{!QLI.SBQQ__Quantity__c}</td> 
        <td >{!QLI.SBQQ__NetTotal__c} </td> 
      </tr>    
    </apex:repeat>
    </table>
  </div> 
</apex:outputPanel>
```

(It also make sense to return already filtered list of QLI__c records directly from apex controller/extension)

In case if apex controller/extension modifications are not possible, then entire calculation can be done in pure Visualforce syntax.

**Template:**

```
<apex:variable  var="additional_discounts_count"  value="{!0}" />  

<apex:repeat var="QLI" value="{!QuoteLines}">
  <apex:variable var="additional_discounts_count" value="{!additional_discounts_count + 1}"  rendered="{!QLI.Trade_In_Discount_Grouping__c == 'Additional Discounts'}"/>
</apex:repeat>

<apex:variable var="table_empty" value="{!additional_discounts_count == 0}" />

<apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered = "{!NOT(table_empty)}" >
  <!-- component -->
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Basically, in visualforce code above we are iterating over **QuoteLines** and increase **additional_discounts_count** for concrete condition only. As a result, counter can be uses to determine if entire table should be shown.

Comment: Controller/VF Component coding works :)